# Make text "flip up"

Tags: html, css

I want to make a piece of text "flip up" as if it is lying on a table and then raised up.
My immediate problem is transform-origin - I can't change the pivot point of my text to "bottom".

```
0% {transform:perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);transform-origin:bottom bottom;}
```

Above fails if I change rotation/pivot point to something like 0% or 40%, like so:

```
0% {transform:perspective(600px) rotateX(90deg);transform-origin:20% 40%;}
```

JS-fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emilius/1c7q9u38/

Comment: i don't understand, could you change the text? I don't understand what table and flip and what's going on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `display: block;` is key here

http://jsfiddle.net/1c7q9u38/1/

```
#test {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    -webkit-animation: flipUp 1s ease-out;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code responsible for the rotation (Flip effect):

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
-ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
```

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Nds4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code---

```
-moz-transform:rotate(-180deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);     
-ms-transform:rotate(-180deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-180deg); 
transform:rotate(-180deg); 
position:absolute;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emilius/1c7q9u38/ - I made this demo you can use